# Please make highlighting of up or down votes on posts more visible on Super User Meta

Tags: feature-request

On all SE sites, the up or down vote arrows next to posts are highlighted if I have already voted on that post. The colours and the highlighting vary on the different sites.

Unfortunately, on Super User Meta, the highlighted arrow is almost indistinguishable from the unhighlighted arrow (both are dark grey, the highlighted version is very slightly darker). In the example below, the red arrow points to the highlighted vote.

[image]

By contrast (pun intended), other SE sites make the highlights far more noticeable, as shown in the following examples.

[image]

Can we please have the highlighting made more noticeable?

Comment: I find that the highlighted arrow becomes much more apparent if I tilt my screen — but, yes, at some angles, it’s almost imperceptible.

Comment: looks fine to me on one screen, less so on the other.

Comment: Looks fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now corrected.

[image]

I assume the change was part of the [new site theme](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13242/super-user-new-site-theme-is-live)